# Using HDD partition as USB drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 And I have an `/archive` partition on my hard drive containing all my personal files, projects, papers, etc. which I would like to present as a "flash drive" via the USB port of my computer, so that additional periphery that I plug into this USB port thinks that a USB stick has been plugged into it [the periphery].

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Solutions involving hints towards new code are of course welcome, if no complete software solution exists.

---

**Edit**: I found this thread on Stack Overflow: “[Simulate a USB flash drive with PC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8613334)”

Which gives a negative to the above question. So, are there USB "on the go" USB sticks with a buffer?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Why do you want to treat a physical hdd as a removal drive, when when using linux, its already possible to deattach a parition on a physical drive.

Answer (score 1):

So you want the Hard Drive partition to be exposed via a USB port so that you can effectively plug it in to another computer or TV?

As the other question suggested, I don't think this is easily done directly as you need a "USB Host" interface to do this whereas the PC USB ports are a consumer rather than a host.

However, there are two possible tricks you can do.

Firstly, you might try an "[Easy Transfer](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Belkin-Windows-Easy-Transfer-Cable/dp/B002L5S6VW)" cable, sometimes called a "[direct transfer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BL6IZO)" cable. These have some basic circuitry for transfering files between 2 computers. They may or may not work very effectively. Personally I've never tried one.

Secondly, you could use something like an [Eye-Fi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye-Fi) card which connects from USB to Wi-Fi rather than USB to USB.

Of course, if both devices has network cards, then a network cable or a shared Wi-Fi connection will always be better and more reliable.

Comment: While you are basically trying to say the right thing your terminology is wrong. The PC provides the USB host as it has control over the bus. A USB host is something you can connect other USB device to.

Comment: Actually, there is a terminology clash at work. If you look at mobile devices, "host mode" refers to making an external USB device (storage) available to the device - the reverse of the normal for mobile devices. On a PC, the USB Host is controller for the USB connections. In this instance, the OP is needing a PC to act as a USB host to another device.